# Unique database for each separate module or one database for all modules

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I've recently come across [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-upload-image-and-save-image-in-project-folder-in-mvc1) in which their database supposedly has several unconnected tables serving different functions in the same Database.

Let me present a hypothetical situation for you to help understand and answer the question better. You're making a website where there is a need for an `Image` database, a `RegisteredUser` database and a `Shop` database.

The above link's example has them all stored in the same database in their own little environments. In other words, all `Image` database related data is stored on the same database as all the `RegisteredUser` database and `Shop` database related data. (ONE DATABASE FOR ALL TABLES - Shop tables not connected to Image tables etc.)

So my questions are:

- First and foremost, is this feasible?
- Is it better to have several different databases for each need?
- I was under the assumption that creating a database with unconnected tables is bad practice. Is this true?
- What are the performance differences between the two options?

Edit: I am using Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC web app. My server management software is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

[image: Here is a diagram of what I'm trying to say]

So in Diagram 1 the three tables represent the `shop` database and the two tables represent the `user` database.

In Diagram 2 the 1st database on the left represents the `shop` database and the 2nd database on the right is the `user` database.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information of this I want tell you why **many databases** are not good for performance.

- I faced with this problem in many time ago and i tried the performance of multi database vs only one database.
  In code , when you want to create a database you should create a *context* class that derived from `DbContext`.
  So you should create many classes and it will using more storage.
- In second scenario you want to access database for inserting, updating and etc.
  For every database you should make connection with a object that instance of your database `context` class so you can imagine how much times will spend while application want to opening connection to `context`.

But all of this reason depends on your application , for example imagine you have a social network with 1m user,you want to create 1m database ? With 1 million `context class`?!

In simple way which one is the best to manage :

1. DATABASE with tables of *user_post* , *user_pictures*,*user_locations* and the other for each user on social network ( every user has one of this database )
2. Having DATABASE for pictures, posts, userInfo and etc and each user has one of this TABLES
3. Having only one DATABASE with TABLE of pictures and etc and each user has one of this row

In summary:

- No this is not possible
- as I told this is the best to having some databases for every titles

**Edit:** as I understand you are agree with second way (having photo, shop,... databases)

Comment: Okay... I'm trying to understand your answer and I'm having a bit of trouble. Using your social media example... Imagine for some strange reason this social media sells products as well - Would you make two databases one for the `users` and all their tables and the other for the `products` and all their tables? OR just use one database? I'll draw a diagram in paint and upload it so as to elaborate.

Comment: @James9oo0 yes this is the best to upload your diagram. i can help you more

Comment: I've just posted it